# How to make the asterisk a part of a counter?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, counters, amsthm

I am writing a usual article in `amsart` style using `amsthm` package to number the theorems.

I need to enumerate certain conditions, while two of them have to bear the same number differing only with an `\ast`. At the moment I found the following solution:

> ```
> \newtheorem {theorem1}{Theorem}[section]
> \newtheorem {theorem_minus_one}{}[section]
> \newtheorem {cond}[theorem1]{}
> \newtheorem{cond_starred}[theorem_minus_one]{*}
>
>
> \setcounter{theorem_minus_one}{\value{theorem1}-1}\label{more_funct}
> \begin{cond_starred}
> More functoriality
> \end{cond_starred}
> ```

Leaving apart the elegance issue, it results in a number of the form  *A.5, where A is the section number and * is the name of `cond_starred`. If I want to refer to it I will need to add the * manually.

I would like the number of this condition to look like A.5*. and the reference number should also be created in this form by the `\ref` command.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like this? We simply abuse the numbering scheme to make `theoremstar` have the same number as the very last previous `theorem`, but with a star added. Remember that two `theoremstar` with no `theorem` in between will get clashing numbers. You can rename `theoremstar` from `Theorem` to `Condition` or to whatever you wish, independently of the name of `theorem`. Just remember that if you rename the environment, you have to change `\thetheoremstar` accordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem {theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem {theoremstar}{Theorem}
\renewcommand\thetheoremstar{*\thetheorem} % this is a very bad abuse, but it works :) 


\begin{document}

\section{My first section}

\begin{theorem}\label{t}
BLA.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theoremstar}\label{tt}
BLA BLE BLI BLO BLU.
\end{theoremstar}

Theorem~\ref{tt} improves Theorem~\ref{t}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that answers my question. I would like to know more about \thetheorem. Do you know any online reference?

Comment: @BorisChorny That's a good question, if I know any online reference. It's surely explained in LaTeX books, but just in short: Unless you use some fancy packages that fiddle with lots of stuff, no macro accesses the counter directly, they use `\the<counter>`. This is true for sectioning commands, page numbers in headers/footers, and most importantly, for `\label`-`\ref`.

Answer (score 9):

Do not beat me up... I could not resist:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{ObelixPro-cyr.ttf}
% the following is shamelessly stolen from tohecz
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{astTheorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand*\asterix{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{ast}}
\renewcommand\theastTheorem{\protect\asterix\thetheorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Asterix the Gaul}
\begin{theorem}\label{1}
    Alea iacta est: The die is cast
\end{theorem}
\begin{astTheorem}\label{2}
    Singularis Porcus: Wild boar
\end{astTheorem}
Theorem~\ref{2} improves Theorem~\ref{1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for nerve. A *truly minor* quibble: Should that be "iacta" instead of "jacta"? (As far as I remember, the letter "J" wasn't a part of the original Roman alphabet...)

Comment: @Mico Caesar definitely said that with an I and not with a J. ;-) Somebody in chat would say that I'm old enough to have heard him saying it.

Comment: I would like to edit the question's title, but…

Comment: @Mico and egreg: yeah, I was in hurry copying quotes from some homepage, before the typo gets corrected in the OP :-)

Comment: Thanks! This is cute, but does not look like a math paper very much. Though in one book on Borsuk theorem the authors used a small picture of a badger (=borsuk in Polish) instead of \qed.

Comment: @BorisChorny I have to say sorry for my mockery, but I had to laugh when I read your mistake in the question and the result of my fooling around got, yes, cute... I leave it if you don't mind.

Comment: Oh, I see now, somebody corrected the mistake before I noticed. I do not mind this kind of mockery.

Answer (score 7):

This allows having the variant theorem anywhere, but requires giving the environment a label as argument. I'd prefer this way, because moving things around when writing the paper can push the variant theorem in a different place and the numbering might go wrong.

The optional argument to `\begin{theorem}` or `\begin{theorem*}` is honored as shown in the example (it's optional, of course).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem*{theoremstar}{Theorem \thmstarnumber}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{theorem*}[1]
 {\edef\thmstarnumber{*\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \let\@currentlabel\thmstarnumber\theoremstar}
 {\endtheoremstar}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{My first section}

\begin{theorem}[S. Else]\label{t}
Bla.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}{t}[W. Ever]\label{tt}
Bla bla bla.
\end{theorem*}

Theorem~\ref{tt} improves Theorem~\ref{t}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

How does it work? I define an unnumbered theorem type with its name depending on the value of a macro that's set at runtime

```
\newtheorem*{theoremstar}{Theorem \thmstarnumber}
```

The value is passed by the environment `theorem*`:

```
\newenvironment{theorem*}[1]
 {\edef\thmstarnumber{*\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \let\@currentlabel\thmstarnumber\theoremstar}
 {\endtheoremstar}
```

The first command sets the value for `\thmstarnumber` as an asterisk followed by the number referred to by the label passed as argument to the environment; we need `\getrefnumber` by `refcount` in order to expand it fully. Then also the current label is set for possible usage of `\label` in the body of the environment and `\theoremstar` starts the unnumbered theorem environment. At the end we simply end the unnumbered theorem.

Not what a beginner would think to, of course. That's why the site exists. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks, that is a great solution, but perhaps a bit beyond my understanding of LaTeX.

Comment: @BorisChorny I added some explanations